# General formula for the carry digit in base-n addition

Tags: finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Sorry if this question has been posted elsewhere.

I was wondering whether there is a general formula for the carry digit when adding two base-$n$ digits. For example, in the case of binary addition, when adding two binary digits $a$ and $b$, their sum $S$ is given by $a \oplus_2 b$, and the carry digit $C$ by $a \cdot_2 b$ (where $\oplus_2$, $\cdot_2$ are base-$2$ addition and multiplication respectively). This can easily been seen by inspecting the binary half adder truth table.

However, consider the corresponding base-$3$ (ternary) truth table:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 a & b & S & C \\\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\\hline
 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\\hline
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\\hline
 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\\hline
 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\\hline
 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\\hline
 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\hline
 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
\end{array}

In this case, it again appears that $S = a\oplus_3 b$ (and it seems obvious to me that this is the case in any base $n$), but clearly $C \neq a \cdot_3 b$. I wouldn't naively expect it to be this simple, and would think that the correct formula could be written in terms of modular addition and multiplication of $a$ and $b$, but I haven't been able to find it (if it even exists).

This seems to be the type of question one may find in a group theory textbook, but it's been a long time since I've read such a book!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For two operands and no carry-in: The obvious formula would compare the sum digit $S$ to one input operand's digit, say $a$. Conceptually, the comparison is done in $\mathbb{Z}$ using the smallest nonnegative remainder representation. If and only if $S < a$, there is a carry-out.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula that does not lift to $\mathbb{Z}$ and only uses mod-base ring operations?

Comment: Hi @ccorn, yeah, I would very much like all the logic to remain in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. As an aside, in the second paragraph of the 'Full adder' section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics), a simple formula is given for the output carry, completely in terms of the ring operations (although this example is slightly different from the half adder I'm considering). But yes, if a formula solely in terms of mod addition and multiplications exists, that would solve my problem.